# Is there a freebase dump that lets me access the schema of Freebase

Tags: freebase, mql

I would like to know what is the expected type of a property. Is there any dump that has this information? I tried to find this in the quad-dump but it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the schema is included in the RDF dump.  Expected type is available as `type.property.expected_type` e.g.

```
ns:people.person.date_of_birth  ns:type.property.expected_type  ns:type.datetime.
```